# Else statement does not execute

Tags: javascript, if-statement

can anyone help me understand why the "else" portion of this code does not execute? 
When the variables equal each other , the alert box appears, when the variables are not the same the else portion does not execute, But if i edit out all, and leave the else portion of code it works

```
$(document).on("click","."+deletebutton,function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if(id){

        if(name1 == p_name){
            alert("I am an alert box!");
        }
        else{
            if(confirm("A League Fee of 14% will be deducted from each players bet amount. This fee is non refundable after you accept. Do you really want to Accept this Match ?"))
            ajax("rid="+id,"del");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: where are `name1` and `p_name` coming from?

Comment: It works for me. On another note - please use proper indentation. This took way more effort to read than it should have (and it will help you write code more easily, too).

Comment: Those are variables , the values in them are the same if i remove the "1", then the alert appears, i simply add 1 to attempt to trigger the "else", Which will not execute for me, BUT! if i remove all the code aside from the if confirm statement it works

Comment: @amadan , thanks for the advice, im a rookie, please excuse me

Comment: provide the html and a fiddle would be better

Comment: Hi @user5420896 As good practices . use name1 === p_name .Also if you want to figure out why its not working.. set breakpoints in the developer tools and try printing out the values of name1 and p_name